# Код виснет, но не выдает ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

В строке перед началом цикла программа "застревает", т.е. не может запустить цикл, другие модули кода работают

```
f = open('clientlist.txt', 'r+')
print('opened file')
print('starting cycle')
for line in f:
    try:
        bot.send_message(line, 'текст сообщения', parse_mode='HTML')
        print(line + ' success')
    except:
        print(line + ' fail')
f.close()
```

на выводе я получаю только

```
opened file
starting cycle
```

В чем ошибка?

Comment: Поставьте print сразу после for. Цикл у вас скорее всего запускается.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У Вас файл пустой. У меня для файла со строчкой "test1" вывелось:

```
opened file
starting cycle
test1
 fail
```

Comment: Вопрос/комментарий. Не имею возможности напрямую поставить комментарий автору

Comment: Вам ничего дрогого не остаётся, как дать ответ без уточнений у автора, или же задать хороший вопрос,  и тем самым заработать репутацию. 50+ даст вам возможность  оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению.

Comment: Теперь, так как автор вопроса  уточнил причину,  вы  можете заменить вопросительную формулировку в ответе на утверждение.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь в освоении